# Joing entities in spring boot with saving output in a hashmap

Tags: java, sql, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

so i wanted to join to entites from database MYSQL ( Client and Facture) in english (User and invoice), the idea is to create statistics  , how many Facture (Invoice) are in a Categorie_client From Client(user)
I created the SQL request but i always get Bad SQL syntax
So here are the screenshots of all what we need :

[Facture entity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mIgRK.png)

[Client entity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iW1WY.png)

[In between CLient and facture entity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VN4D1.png)

[The sql syntax](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4h1KV.png)

[The map implementation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5iovj.png)

the error i get :
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '.example.demo.utils.ClientFacture(F.ID_FACTURE, C.ID_CLIENT, COUNT(*)) FROM F...' at line 1

If i turn the nativeQuery = False or i remove it i get A error about @Bean implementation.

Hibernate version : 5.4.32

Every help is welcome it's for Uni project
Thanks in advance.

Comment: you used GROUP BY C.CATEGORY_CLIENT but it is not on selected fields and only you can select grouped fields so F.ID_FACTURE,C.ID_CLIENT cannot be selected.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.